# Dedekind domains problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $D$ is a Dedekind domain where each maximal ideal is principal, then how can I show that $D$ is a Principal Ideal Domain?

I need your help, thank you.

Comment: Hint: analagous to this proof for positive integers: if a multiplicative submonoid contains every prime then it contains every positive integer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: A product of principal ideals is principal.

Comment: But, in $D$ there are ideals that can be not maximal? 
Because, if I can say that every ideal in $D$ is maximal then is principal, and therefore I could use that the product of principal ideals is principal, so $D$ principal ideal domain.

This argument is correct?

Comment: @rgl4: A product of maximal ideals is never a maximal ideal in a Dedekind domain; in particular, there are always infinitely many nonmaximal ideals. Your argument, if I understand it correctly, is wrong, and doesn't really use the hint I provided.